# Return statement within an if statement and printing it out to a file

Tags: java, if-statement, return

I'm working on a punch in/punch out type program. I am doing it out of fun to practice my coding. I just finished my Java 1 class so I know very little about the vastness of Java. Because of this my code is going to be using a lot of techniques and methods that can be replaced and done more efficiently by more advanced techniques but right now that isn't what I want.

I have a class where I have my most messy methods. In this class I create employees, I allow them to check-in, and I allow them to check-out. Each check-in and check-out is printed out to a file. As part of my program I have a method to find the difference between the time in and time out and give the elapsed time as well as print it to the file.

The program displays the time elapsed in the console perfectly, but when it writes to the file it prints null. In my method to calculate the elapsed time, I don't understand why my return statements within the if statements are being ignored and it is going straight to null instead of returning the proper elapsed time. The reason I have `null` is because my compiler told me to add it because it was missing the return statement.

```
public static String timeOut() {
  Date startDate;
  Date endDate;

  for (int i = 0; i < date.size(); i = i + 1) {
    for (int j = 0; j < date2.size(); j = j + 1) {
      if (date.get(i).getAcctNumber().equals(date2.get(j).getAcctNumber())) {
        startDate = date.get(i).getDate();
        endDate = date2.get(j).getDate();
        long duration = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

        // This is a continues program that doesn't close, so i remove the
        // values from array after i use them to avoid confusion when finding
        // the time elapsed. Otherwise the array will be to big and have
        // duplicates
        date.remove(i);
        date2.remove(j);

        long diffSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
        if (diffSeconds < 60) {
          return "You have been out for " + diffSeconds + " Seconds ";
        }
        if (diffSeconds > 60 && diffSeconds < 3600) {
          long diffMinutes = (diffSeconds / 60);

          long difference = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(diffMinutes);
          diffSeconds = (diffSeconds - difference);

          return "You have been out for " + diffMinutes + " Minutes "
              + " and " + diffSeconds + " Seconds ";
        }
        else if (diffSeconds >= 3600) {
          long diffMinutes = (diffSeconds / 60);
          long diffHours = (diffMinutes / 60);
          long difference = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(diffMinutes);
          diffSeconds = (diffSeconds - difference);

          long diff = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(diffHours);
          diffMinutes = (diffMinutes - diff);

          return "You have been out for " + diffHours + "Hours: "
              + diffMinutes + " :Minutes " + diffSeconds + " :Seconds";
        }
      }
      else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Above is my "find time elapsed" method, and I want to know why it prints `null` to the file. Please note I am calling this method in another part of my code. I am writing it to file as follows:

```
File log = new File("log.txt");
FileWriter s = new FileWriter("log.txt", true);
PrintWriter q = new PrintWriter(s);

for (int j = 0; j < emp.size(); j++) {
  if (emp.get(j).getAcctNumber().equals(en)) {
    q.println(emp.get(j) + " " + "Checked OUT on:" + " " + d + " " + timeOut());
  }
}
q.close();
```

This is just a small portion of my check-in method where the user can check back in to the system. It shows how I am writing it to the file.
The following is the output found in the file:

> Parker , Peter 55 Checked OUT on: Mon May 12 20:42:07 EDT 2014
>
> Parker , Peter 55 Checked IN on: Mon May 12 20:42:11 EDT 2014 null

I really don't know what is happening and I feel like it has an easy solution, but I have searched and troubleshooted with no avail.

```
public class DatesCLI {

  public String empnum;
  public Date d = new Date();

  public DatesCLI(String en, Date date) {
    d = date;
    empnum = en;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format(empnum) + " " + d;
  }

  public Date getDate() {
    return d;
  }

  public String getAcctNumber() {
    return empnum;
  }

}
```

These are the arrays I create:

```
private static ArrayList<DatesGUI> date = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<DatesGUI> date2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Try q.flush() before q.close().

Comment: Didn't work, it still prints out null.

Comment: Can't you just go step by step with the debugger? Check what the value of `diffSeconds ` and why it doesn't go into an `if`.

Comment: The compiler told you that you needed to add that return statement because you did not account for all logical flows with the prior 3 statements (this is why I find it best practice to consolidate to 1 return statement if possible).  It is a little hard to read without proper indents but looks like to reach that last return statement `diffSeconds = 60` for it looks like you account for `< 60 and > 60` but no `=` to

Comment: We need your full time elapsed method and the context from where it's called

Comment: The thing is that the function works, in the console it displays the time elapsed perfectly, but it is just when it goes to print it to the file that it prints null.

Comment: What are date and date2? If they are Collections then you can't call remove while iterating over them. You'll need to get an iterator and iterate over that.

Comment: sorry but it is too hard to read the code without good indentation :(

Comment: Date and Date2 are arrays that are made up of an employee number and the date they clocked out.  @Josh

Comment: @Zerok00l I suspect they are not arrays but Lists or some other Collection type. Arrays in Java do not have a size() method but rather a length property. In that case removing while iterating will cause all sorts of weirdness though I suspect it may not be the whole story.

Comment: I added the Date class

Comment: I guess what i really want to know is why is it that it prints out the last return statement "return null" and not any of the other return statements, when it displays them just fine in console?

Comment: @Zerok00l You appear to be missing the case when it's been exactly 60 seconds. What data are you using in your tests?

Comment: Can you finally run a debugger and tell us the value of `diffSeconds` inside `timeOut`?

Comment: the value of diffSeconds is always changing. When a person clocks out then it assigns a date, when they clock in it assigns a second date. diffSeconds is the difference of this value as seconds.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I call timeOut twice in my program. The first time it prints to terminal just fine. During this first instance however i remove the Date values from the arrays. So when i called it the second time there was nothing in the array to find so it would print out null. Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to run through the code with the debugger.  I feel like your code isnt running through the if statement in your TimeOut function.  If this is happen you are more than likely outputting null.

I did realize you posted this question almost 30 days ago,  if you havnt figured it out by know let me know and ill try and look into it farther for you.